# primary keys, max limit

Tags: sql, database

I have questions regarding SQL and autoincremented primary keys. what is the maximum limit of a autoincremented primary key? if the limit ever becomes a problem, say you have used up all the primary keys. what can you do then?

Just looking for knowledge around the topic. Regarding what database I am talking about. Again i'm looking for knowledge. So any type of database.

Comment: An INT will take you up to 2,147,483,647.

A BIGINT will get you 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: ok so it's not really a issue needed to be considered. good to know!

Comment: Probably **depends** on **what concrete database product** you're using. The **SQL** language standard itself doesn't define anything in this regard - this is very much **vendor-specific** (so please add a relevant tag for the concrete database you're using).

Comment: If you are concerned about the maximum size, you can start the sequence below zero, and thus double the capacity

Comment: Understood. I am actually interested to understand any sql database actually. i will add that to the question.

Comment: This depends on database you are using. so its vendor specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is related to the datatype itself, not with the fact of being auto increment.If you are concerned about the maximum size, you can start the sequence below zero, and thus double the capacity, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [MYTABLE](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(-2147483648,1),
    (...)
```

While the ranges of values for different data type are like this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql

1. **bigint** - 
   **Range:** *-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)* 
   **Storage:** *8 Bytes*
2. **int** - **Range:** *-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)* **Storage:** *4 Bytes*
3. **smallint** - **Range** *-2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)* **Storage:** *2 Bytes*
4. **tinyint** - **Range** *0 to 255* **Storage:** *1 Bytes*

Comment: Thats sounds like a great idea. Good to know. Thanks

Comment: Why link to MS SQL Server side, which includes non-ANSI SQL types, when the question has no dbms specified?

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for the clarification, But he is just looking for knowledge, so i gave it. Correct me if I am wrong